# Is this a valid XSS filter?

Tags: xss

Is this a valid xss filter?

```
private String cleanXSS(String value) {
  //You'll need to remove the spaces from the html entities below
  value = value.replaceAll("<", "& lt;").replaceAll(">", "& gt;");
  value = value.replaceAll("\(", "& #40;").replaceAll("\)", "& #41;");
  value = value.replaceAll("'", "& #39;");
  value = value.replaceAll("eval\((.*)\)", "");
  value = value.replaceAll("[\"\'][\s]javascript:(.)[\"\']", """");
  value = value.replaceAll("(?i)script", "");
  return value;
}
```

Comment: If it was this simple, there would be no framework that's vulnerable to xss. :)

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't.

Your javascript URLs detection can easily be bypassed. Here's a quick example: (all these links will call the `alert` function in the latest version of Google Chrome)

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="javaSCRIPT:alert('gotcha 1')">click me 1</a>
    <a href="java&#09;script:alert('gotcha 2')">click me 2</a>
    <a href="java&#09script:alert('gotcha 3')">click me 3</a>
    <a href="java&#0000000000009script:alert('gotcha 4')">click me 4</a>
    <a href="&#x6a;&#x61;&#x76;&#x61;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;:alert('gotcha 5')">click me 5</a>
    <a href="java&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;:alert('gotcha 6')">click me 6</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Generating secure JavaScript code presents its own challenges. Generating secure HTML code comes with its own too. It is unlikely that you can come up with a single universal method that works in both context. Escaping and encoding is always contextual.

You really should leverage battle-tested libraries for this.